# Robot framework plugin doesn't appear in post build step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have Jenkins 2.150.3 installed. I have installed the Robot Framework plugin for test reports publishing. But it does not appear in the post build step.
I have installed all the dependency plugins too. Can some one help what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check the [dependencies of the JENKINS/Robot Framework Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin): you have installed those, but check their versions.

Second, check if [robotframework itself is correctly installed](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/INSTALL.rst).
Check if the type of job can change whether or not you do see it in the post build steps.

The [`src/test/java/hudson/plugins/robot/RobotProjectActionTest.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/robot-plugin/blob/851fa19bcd338fcc32c00762d76aa3596a201b83/src/test/java/hudson/plugins/robot/RobotProjectActionTest.java) shows that plugin used in a Freestyle project, as a build step (*not* post-build).
See if that robot is available as a build step then.